# muli element inside bootstrap button - button deforms

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem with the bootstrap button, when I put 2 elements such as div or span inside it the little arrow inside the button will go below the button text. it's like it will get a float (left or right) attribute and it will make the elements get ordered vertically.

---

```
<!--HTML Part-->
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-white dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="english">Site Language</span><span class="farsi">زبان سایت</span>
</button>
```

```
/*CSS Part*/
.english {display: none !important;}

.farsi {
        display: none !important;
        direction: rtl;
        font-family: 'Lalezar';
        text-align: right;
       }

.english:lang(en), .farsi:lang(fa) {
        display: block !important;
        }
```

-

```
//JS Part
<script>
function changelang2fa() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].setAttribute("lang", "fa");
}

function changelang2en() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].setAttribute("lang", "en");
}
</script>
```

Normally the button is:

[image: Normally the button is]

deformed style with having span tag inside:

[image]

P.S. : i intend to make my website multilingual (English and Farsi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to get into the details of how you can use alternate ways to achieve what you are doing, but instead will just tell you where you went wrong in your code. `<span>` elements should get a `display:inline` which will make the down arrow appear right beside it. Giving it a `display:block` like you have done, causes the arrow to appear in the next line.

```css
.english {display: none !important;}

.farsi {
        display: none !important;
        direction: rtl;
        font-family: 'Lalezar';
        text-align: right;
       }

.english:lang(en), .farsi:lang(fa) {
        display: inline !important;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<!--HTML Part-->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-white dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="english">Site Language</span><span class="farsi">زبان سایت</span>
</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rocks, I got the idea but changed it a bit and it worked out ;)
`span.english:lang(en) {display: inline !important;}` &
`span.farsi:lang(fa) {display: inline !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper Bootstrap 4 drop-down button instead of trying to re-invent the wheel. Bootstrap 4 already has invented, created and polished all the "wheels" you'll ever need.

Here's a working code example (click "run code snippet" below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-white dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Site Language
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">English</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-right" href="#">زبان سایت</a>
    </div>
</div>
```